# gulp-typescript not able to transpile my project ts files

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp

Not really sure as what's wrong with the below configuration, but for some reason it doesn't want to transpile my project's ts files. As shown below, it doesn't even throw any errors while running the gulp task. It just runs as if everything was ok and produces no .js files whatsoever,  neither creates the build directory.

(also tested in Admin mode, but no luck)

Everything works when I manually run `tsc -p config/tsconfig.json`

**versions:**

```
    λ gulp -v
    [00:13:03] CLI version 1.2.2
    [00:13:03] Local version 3.9.1

    +-- typescript@2.1.5

    λ node -v
    v6.9.4
```

**Project directory structure:**

- src/

  - app/ ( contains all the app ts files )
- config/

  - tsconfig.json
- gulpfile.js
- package.json

**gulpfile.js**:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
const tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var config = {
  jit: {
    root: './build/jit',
    index: 'index-jit.html'
  },
  aot: {
    root:'./build/aot/dist',
    index: 'index-aot.html'
  }
};

 gulp.task("compile:jit", () => {
  let tsProject = tsc.createProject("config/tsconfig.json");

  log("[JIT] Compiling all .ts files")
    let tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsProject());

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(".", {sourceRoot: '/src'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(tsProject.options.outDir));
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "outDir": "../build/jit/app",
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "typeRoots": [
          "../node_modules/@types/"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "../src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules",
        "../src/**/*-aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

The only output I get when running `gulp -LLLL compile:jit`

```
[23:49:34] Using gulpfile [project_dir]/gulpfile.js
[23:49:34] Starting 'compile:jit'...
[23:49:34] [JIT] Compiling all .ts files
[23:49:34] Finished 'compile:jit' after 75 ms
```

Comment: What version of typescript/tsc gulp-typescript are you using? Is there a git-project we can checkout and compile/try out ourselves? Because I don't see an immediate problem indeed :/ -
Ref to https://github.com/aredfox/electron-starter - I seem to have a similar setup which I can run without a problem.
PS; not that it would affect the outcome, byt "typeRoots" isn't necessary anymore when using "npm i @types/<package> --save(--dev)" - as it'll look for it automatically now.

Comment: ps; I see you're using the "outDit" from the tsConfig.. Have you tried defining gulp.dest('./some/path/') to see what's going on?
On another note, why I asked to a git repo we can clone is that I found that the tsc and gulp-typescript sometimes fail silently indeed - and are difficult to debug when there's no output.

Comment: I've updated the post with Typescript version. I will try to put together an example for you to see the whole project. The thing is, that I'm using the same configuration on other computer with win7 and everything is working just fine.. Now when I copy it and then build the project with the the same configs on my other pc ( win 10,) it doesn't seem to work. I will also double check if the version of tsc, node gulp are the same.. but still I don't see any reason why it should not work.

Comment: not seeing a particular reason either.. Have you installed gulp and typescript globally as well? An example would be useful - maybe also try getting it out on the GitHub pages of typescript's issue page, they might be able to refer or help you as well. I'll be waiting for your example!

Comment: I'm using typescript 2.5 at the moment - maybe try updating (it's new & stable), do you need 2.1 specifically? Maybe try out [my git repo](https://github.com/aredfox/electron-starter) - you can just clone / and npm install / and then edit node_modules/@types/dot-object/index.d.ts - [as there's an error waiting to be solved](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/14320) - just fix pick's return value from void to any. If [my repo](https://github.com/aredfox/electron-starter) doesn't run over there as well then :( :/.. Here it does win7/10 macOS and linux mint - so try and look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that the files couldn't be processed cause gulp was not able to read my path, since it was containing a "non-standard" path character.

```
C:/[Dev]/Project
```

Obviously it was the square brackets causing the issue, cause when I moved the project to `C:/Project` , everything suddenly started working.